# How to use regex to replace some parentheses but not others

Tags: python, regex

As the title says, I am trying to replace parentheses with brackets conditionally.
For example, I will have a string like:

"(This is some text) but I also have (1) character and not (22) character." The character may be 1 but it could be any singe character.

I only want to replace the text that has one character in it. So the above example will be:

"(This is some text) but I also have **[**1**]** character and not (22) character."

I have tried using this regex which almost works but I can't get text to remain inside:

```
re.sub("\(.\)", "\[.\]", a)
```

Edit:
Added clarity that it could be any single character within the parentheseses

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html?#re.sub):

```py
>>> x = '(This is some text) but I also have (1) character and not (22) character.'
>>> re.sub('\((.)\)', '[\g<1>]', x)
'(This is some text) but I also have [1] character and not (22) character.'
```

You need to *capture* this one character and then use the capture group number to retrieve it.

Answer (score 2):

Use a capture group:

```py
inp = "(This is some text) but I also have (1) character and not (22) character."
output = re.sub(r'\((.)\)', r'[\1]', inp)
print(output)
```

This prints:

```
(This is some text) but I also have [1] character and not (22) character.
```

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity. I edited the question above. It may or may not be a 1, it could be any one character.

Comment: @Penrouk There is nothing about my answer which presumes what the single character is, it could be anything.  Not sure what you mean by your comment.

Answer (score 0):

use `{}` to control how many characters is your target.

```
re.sub(r"\((.{1})\)", r"[\1]", a)
```

Comment: That's not the problem, and `.` or `.{1}` mean the same thing.

Comment: you are right, I just constructed a demo, if he wants to replace 2,3, or more characters.